# Can I make an environment which treats the first paragraph differently to the rest?

Tags: environments, indentation

I am trying to make a new environment which creates a hanging indent on the first paragraph only but leaves the other paragraphs indented:

[image]

My code for the above image is:

```
    \begin{hang}
        This should hopefully be a hanging line of text. This should hopefully have a hanging line of text.
    \end{hang}

    {\leftskip  0.4 in
    \rightskip  0.4 in
        This should hopefully not have a hanging line of text. \par
    }
```

where the `hang` environment I've defined is

```
\newenvironment{hang}{ % begin def
        \leftskip   0.4 in
        \rightskip  0.4 in
        \parindent  -0.4 in%
    }{ %end def
        \par%
    }
```

but I need `\parindent  -0.4 in` to act *only* on the first paragraph.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't set `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` directly in latex unless you know there will never be any kind of latex display environment/list within the scope of the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{hang}
{\list{}{%
\parindent1cm
\itemindent-1cm
}\item[]}
{\endlist}
\begin{document}

\begin{hang}
This should hopefully be a hanging line of text.
This should hopefully have a hanging line of text.
This should hopefully be a hanging line of text.
This should hopefully have a hanging line of text.

This should hopefully be a hanging line of text.
This should hopefully have a hanging line of text.
This should hopefully be a hanging line of text.
This should hopefully have a hanging line of text.
\end{hang}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Inventive! Thank you. How could I extend this to mirror the parindent on the right hand side of the paragraph?

Comment: @HarrySmith not so inventive: _all_ latex display environments are made this way, `center`, `quote`, `verbatim` etc are all one item lists. You can bring the right margin in just by setting `\rightmargin`, latex doesn't by default support changing the right margin of just the first line, if that's what you mean.